# jQuery - Stop child hover triggering parent click with relative elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

This is not a duplicate question. I've looked around stackoverflow and none of the following questions have worked for me.

[jQuery stop child elements animate on hover of parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666839/jquery-stop-child-elements-animate-on-hover-of-parent)
[How to have click event ONLY fire on parent DIV, not children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183381/how-to-have-click-event-only-fire-on-parent-div-not-children)

I have a parent element `.cover` and a single child element inside called `.details-wrapper`

When i hover over the child element of the parent, the parent hover is being triggered. This is how i want it to be (Sorry about editing);

[image]

Currently what i have tried (And failed) is using `return false;` and `stopPropagation`

The image has `position: relative` and `top: 160px` so it comes out of the original `.cover` wrapper

It's really weird because the way i hover ovre the element determines how the jquery works. Here's a gif showing that.

https://gyazo.com/7153f3b8d3a57d0cfbb6b8d7d56caf0a

The jQuery i'm using is:

```
$(".cover").not('.details-wrapper').hover(function(e) {
    if (e.target === this) {
        $(".cover").css("background","url(url1), url('"+cover._url+"')");
    }
}, function() {
    $(".cover").css("background","url('"+cover._url+"')");
});
```

I'm unsure how I can fix this so when i hover over the child element it stops the hover for the parent from triggering.

Just for further clarity, this doesnt work either:

```
$(".cover").hover(function(e) {
    if (e.target === this) {
        $(".cover").css("background","url(url1), url('"+cover._url+"')");
    }
}, function() {
    $(".cover").css("background","url('"+cover._url+"')");
});

$(".cover .details-wrapper").hover(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't rely on the `.hover()` function, which is a shorthand for the `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()` events. You need the `.mouseover()` and `.mouseout()` events, and it will trigger appropriately when entering/leaving child nodes:

```
$(function() {
  $('.cover').on('mouseover', function(e) {
      if (e.target === this) {
        $('.cover').css('background','url(url1), url(''+cover._url+'')');
      }
    })
    .on('mouseout', function() {
       $('.cover').css('background','url(''+cover._url+'')');
    });
});
```

The simple explanation is this: when you are using `.hover()` (hence the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` were being listened), they are not triggered when you enter or leave the child elements. This causes the event to appear to be 
"propagated" because in the background, the `mouseleave` event was never called when you enter the child. However, the `mouseout` event will be called, resulting in the desired behaviour.

Here is a proof-of-concept example (using a red background to indicate `mouseover` events):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.cover').on('mouseover', function(e) {
      if (e.target === this) {
        $('.cover').css('background', 'red');
      }
    })
    .on('mouseout', function() {
      $('.cover').css('background', 'transparent');
    });
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.cover {
  padding: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 10rem;
}
.cover .details-wrapper {
  background-color: #eee;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 2rem;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cover">
  Cover
  <div class="details-wrapper">
    Details wrapper
  </div>
</div>
```

There is a thread on SO that discusses the difference between these events: [Jquery mouseenter() vs mouseover()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286532/jquery-mouseenter-vs-mouseover)

Comment: This sorted my problem perfectly. Thanks a lot for the time spent to write and add the reasoning behind it!